# How to get material edit text in UiAutomator test

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

I have TextInputLayout in my layout

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_text_input"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/email_address"
            android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

and I set error to email_text_input

```
 email_text_input.error = getString(R.string.please_enter_a_valid_email)
```

How can i check if error is shown in my UiAutomated tests?

Comment: UiAutomator tests are mainly for black-box testing. Here you are testing your own app with access to source code. I would suggest to use espresso test in this scenario. In espresso you can easily check for valid input.

Comment: @SushantSomani Do you know how to do that with espresso?

Comment: This link can help you. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso